# Javascript - Select element by id name

Tags: javascript

Normally I select elements with an id via `document.getElementById('idName')`. But apparently you can also select them by name only 'idName'. I was not aware of this until recently. I wanted to know if this is a "bad practice" to select elements by their idName? I have already used the search engine and found nothing about `select by id name`. So here is my question now.

[image]

```js
 console.log(idName)
```

```html
<div id="idName">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: Is this possible? I thought id or class would inherently be a reference to the element and not the element itself.

Comment: @DragonInTraining It is possible. You can open your dev tools and type: footer into the console.

Comment: It could happen that a variable is declared with the same name causing conflicting code.

Comment: If you were coding in the 90's you would understand where it came from. lol You people missed out on document.all and documnet.layers wars. :) Those were the days. And I just dated myself.....

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: This is blowing my mind a little. I understand that this might not be BiP but the fact that the option exists is amazing.

Comment: @DragonInTraining for me too :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bad practice because you can get yourself confused and cause conflicts with your own js variables.

Comment: I also think that it should be used with caution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say it's Good or bad But

you should be very careful while using . This can cause many problems So I will recommend use in Small Projects only .
(it's My personal recommendation )

Suppose Your JavaScript loads First then it will throw an error and none of the code will work

[For more Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables)

just typing in 'idName' isn’t a “short form” of document.getElementById()  It’s a reference to a global variable

Comment: I see it the same way you do. I would have no problem using it for smaller projects. But for larger ones, it can lead to problems.